# img naturalWidth unexpected return value

Tags: javascript, html

I have this responsive image :

```
<img 
    class="post-card-image" 
    srcset="/content/images/size/w300/2021/04/photo-1459411552884-841db9b3cc2a.jpeg 300w,
           /content/images/size/w600/2021/04/photo-1459411552884-841db9b3cc2a.jpeg 600w,
           /content/images/size/w1000/2021/04/photo-1459411552884-841db9b3cc2a.jpeg 1000w,
           /content/images/size/w2000/2021/04/photo-1459411552884-841db9b3cc2a.jpeg 2000w"
   sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 600px, (min-width: 768px) 50vw, 100vw" 
   src="/content/images/size/w600/2021/04/photo-1459411552884-841db9b3cc2a.jpeg"
   alt="Publishing options"
   loading="lazy" />
```

When simulating an iPhone X (375x812 DPR:3) on firefox, I can see that the 2000w image was loaded by checking `img.currentSrc`.

My problem is when I check `img.naturalWith`, this gives me the value `375` which is exactly `100vw`. I was expecting this to return the image's original width `2000` or maybe `2000/3 = 666`.

My question is why does `img.naturalWith` returns the value `375` in this particular case ?

#### Edit

Here is a [demo of the problem](https://codepen.io/ramrami/pen/mdRoqGg).

```js
const img1 = document.getElementById("img-with-srcset");
const img2 = document.getElementById("img-no-srcset");

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log('page is fully loaded');
  
  console.log("img1.naturalWidth : ", img1.naturalWidth);
  console.log("img1.currentSrc : ", img1.currentSrc);
  document.getElementById('meta-1').innerHTML = `Natural Width: ${img1.naturalWidth}<br/>Current src : ${img1.currentSrc}`;

  console.log("img2.naturalWidth : ", img2.naturalWidth);
  console.log("img2.currentSrc : ",img2.currentSrc);
  document.getElementById('meta-2').innerHTML = `Natural Width: ${img2.naturalWidth}<br/>Current src : ${img2.currentSrc}`;  
});
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  }
}

.card-image {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}

.card-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img  id="img-with-srcset"
     srcset="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509587584298-0f3b3a3a1797?w=400 400w,
             

https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509587584298-0f3b3a3a1797?w=600 600w,
                    
https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509587584298-0f3b3a3a1797?w=800 800w,

https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509587584298-0f3b3a3a1797?w=2000 2000w" 
sizes="(min-width: 1200px) 600px, (min-width: 768px) 50vw, 100vw" 
src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509587584298-0f3b3a3a1797?w=2000" alt="Writing posts" />  
    </div>  
    <div class="card-meta" id="meta-1"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-image">
      <img  
           id="img-no-srcset"
           src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509587584298-0f3b3a3a1797?w=2000" 
           alt="Writing posts"
       />  
    </div>  
    <div class="card-meta" id="meta-2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And a screen shot when simulating an iPhone X (375x812 DPR:3) on firefox :

[image]

The first image has `srcset` and `sizes` attr, the second does not. You can see that the same image (w=2000) was loaded in both cases by checking `currentSrc`, but the value of naturalWidth is different. The CSS is the same for both images.

Thank you

Comment: Because [that's what it's defined as doing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/naturalWidth). The MDN page goes into a fair bit of detail, so it's probably worth reading the whole thing (thankfully, not _super_ long).

Comment: I did read that before posting here, it says "This is the width at which the image is naturally drawn when no constraint or specific value is established for the image.",  That's why I expected the value to be 2000

Comment: In the MDN example, they're using a 400x398 image with 200px in css, naturalWith returns 400. In my case I am using a 2000x2450 rendered at 100vw (375), naturalWith gives me 375 instead of 2000

Comment: Are you definitely waiting for whichever image is chosen to be loaded, eg with an onload handler? MDN state that they run the code in conjunction with load handling. Just having a src may not be enough.

Comment: Look at the example where it's set to 100% width though: now the natural width is the viewport's width in CSS pixels, corrected for DPI scaling. So: what CSS does your `<img>` actually have applied to it? I.e. what is `.post-card-image` defined as?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes I run my js code on image load event

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the image has position absolute and width 100% on a container that is 100vw with some padding

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the weird thing is that if I remove the attr `srcset` and `sizes` and just leave `src` with the `2000x2450` image, I get naturalWidth = 2000, with the same CSS

Comment: Right, so you've assigned the image a width:100%, which means its natural width is going to be the CSS pixel measure of "whatever the parent container's width is", not the number of pixels that the file encodes. On that note: please update your post to show that CSS, ideally as a runnable snippet because this is something that you should be able to create an [MCVE] for so that people can point to very specific parts of your code as being responsible for what you're seeing.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I updated the post with a link to a demo and a screenshot of the problem. Thank you

Comment: Please try to turn that into a runnable snippet in your post: as per the [posting guidelines](/help/how-to-ask), links to external code is fine but _only in addition to_ having the relevant code in your post. In this case, you should be able to just put a runnable snippet in your post so that we can click "run" right here, and see the result (with console output right in the post itself. It's quite convenient).  Also note that your link doesn't show any code: it only shows a result, so that's not a good link to include.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you for your answer and sorry for not giving any feedback this far. I read you answer when you first posted it and I realized that I needed to sit down and read those specs very carefully which I didn't have time to. I will definitely come back to this. Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

naturalWidth/Height returns the intrinsic **density-corrected** width/height of the image.

I guess what's the intrinsic dimension is, is pretty clear for a bitmap image like a JPEG.
The hard bit is what does "density corrected" mean.

Internally when an image source is selected it has a [*current-pixel-density*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#current-pixel-density) value. This value is determined as follow ([specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#normalizing-the-source-densities)):

- If the image source is selected from the `src` of the image, it's `1`.
- If the image source is selected from the `srcset` attribute and it has a [pixel-density-descriptor](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#pixel-density-descriptor) (n`x`), this descriptor's value is used.
- If the image source is selected from the `srcset` attribute and it has a [width-descriptor](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/images.html#width-descriptor), then the pixel density represents the width descriptor value divided by the used **source size**. This *source size* is one that is defined in the `sizes` attribute of the `<source>`.

Here we are in the third case.
To make it a bit less dynamic, let's set an unique `50vw` value in the `sizes` attribute.

```js
const img1 = document.getElementById("img-with-srcset");

window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log("img1.naturalWidth : ", img1.naturalWidth);
  console.log("img1.currentSrc : ", img1.currentSrc);
  const src = img1.currentSrc;
  const width_descriptor = src.slice(src.lastIndexOf("w=") + 2);
  // in our case the intrinsic width is the same as width_descriptor
  const intrinsic_width = width_descriptor;
  const source_size = innerWidth * 0.5; // 50vw
  const density = width_descriptor / source_size;
  const expected_size = intrinsic_width / density;
  console.log( "expected : ", expected_size );
});
```

```html
<img  id="img-with-srcset"
  srcset="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509587584298-0f3b3a3a1797?w=400 400w,
    https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509587584298-0f3b3a3a1797?w=600 600w,
    https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509587584298-0f3b3a3a1797?w=800 800w,
    https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509587584298-0f3b3a3a1797?w=2000 2000w" 
  sizes="50vw" 
  src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1509587584298-0f3b3a3a1797?w=2000" alt="Writing posts" />
```

So in this case of not having a *pixel-density-descriptor*, the naturalWidth/Height values do depend on the selected `size` value, which can be itself relative to the viewport's size.

Not knowing what you are willing to do it's hard to go further, but note that [there is a proposal](https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/6532) to expose the current size of a `<source>` going on.

Comment: Thanks. So I guess we should not use `naturalWidth` to get the "real" img width in the file ?

Comment: Yeah, they kinda broke it in my mind... you can still use an offscren image though, using the `currentSrc`.

Answer (score 0):

You can download image again with js and then get image intrinsic size.

```js
const getImageIntrinsicSize = async (src) => {
    const image = new Image();

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        image.onload = () => resolve({
            w: image.naturalWidth, 
            h: image.naturalHeight
        });

        image.src = src;
    })
}
```